# jQuery keypress is not working with dynamic textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working in an application where i have to use keypress event for the data manipulation on dynamic textboxes.But the problem is that when i am trying to apply the  keypress event on the dynamic text box then  it is not working,I am giving a fiddle .[This is  the exmaple](http://jsfiddle.net/info2jeet/hfmjajce/)

```
$("#DynamicTextBox").keypress(function (e) {
     alert('hiii');
  });
```

I want to apply keypress on DynamicTextBox,myPicker1,myPicker2 but it is not working

Comment: somebody please  help

Comment: Use event delegation. `$(document).on('#DynamicTextBox', 'keypress', function{....});`

Comment: look for event delegation

Comment: @Tushar can you use my fiddle i have created one

Comment: @lucifer CHeck [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/hfmjajce/1/). Look at the bottom of code for `on()`

Comment: you are not giving any element an d ="DynamicTextBox", you are just giving it a name="..." and you are trying to call a function with ID.

Comment: @Tushar  i saw your demo but what i want that i will type something in the DynamicTextBox and the value will be  passed  inside the keypress function ,can you do that please

Comment: @lucifer Did you see the demo closely, I've updated the value of button using the value in the textbox, Use `$(this).val()`, inside the event handler to get the value from the textbox

Comment: @Tushar if i want  3 textbox values then what i have to do ??

Comment: @lucifer Get the values normally using `val()`. `$('#dynamicText1').val()`, `$('#dynamicText2').val()`, etc.

Comment: and why only first textbox supplying value??

Comment: it wil be very useful if you update the fiddle  with all textboxes having value i am not getting

Comment: @Tushar $('#dynamicText1').val() not giving the values

Comment: @Tushar why your fiddle does not work on 1 st keypress

Comment: @lucifer I hope the problem of event binding on dynamic elements is solved, if you have other problems ask another question